# FBO Inclomplete Errors in OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

I am having an issue with getting a framebuffer incomplete attachment error on the FBO initialized from this code:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo_handle);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_handle);

GLuint render_tex;
glGenTextures(1, &render_tex);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, render_tex);
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA4, size.x, size.y);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, render_tex, 0);

GLuint depthBuf;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuf);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuf);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, size.x, size.y);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuf);

GLenum drawBuffers[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Not really sure where to go from here because everything looks like it should work to me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should probably unbind the texture and render buffer once you've attached them. And I think it might be the internal format of your texure, the implementatin may not like rendering to RGB4. Check what glCheckFramebufferStatus​ returns.

Comment: Just by calling glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0), correct? glCheckFramebufferStatus returns framebuffer_incomplete_attachment like I mentioned above

Comment: Yes, same to unbind the renderbuffer. I thought you were just referring to the state machine error. Try it with the texure set to GL_RGB8 since that must work on all complient implementations.

Comment: Unfortunately, unbinding the texture and renderbuffer did nothing. Neither did using GL_RGB8 instead of RGBA4. Any other ideas?

Comment: I mentioned the unbinding mostly because it's just a good idea. You might want to write yourself a little macro that calls `glGetError()`, checks the return value, and prints something if there's an error. Then just sprinkle it liberally around your code leading up to the point where you check the framebuffer for completeness. (Particularly a version that does nothing unless DEBUG is defined is good to have lots of all over your code). You could also use ARB_debug_output but that's more work

Comment: I would be curious to know what `size.x` and `size.y` are, if it is complaining about incomplete attachments. `GL_RGBA4` is not guaranteed to be a color-renderable format (in desktop GL) as pointed out elsewhere, but I do not think that is the issue here.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no errors anywhere before I check the framebuffer. Check very frequently.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman size.x and size.y are the window sizes. Passed in by the main method.

Comment: Upon further investigation, the size was being passed before the first draw, and thus they were 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the size was being passed before being set because the first draw was not occurring. Many thanks to @AndonM.Coleman